# MySQL: List instructors (names) who taught a section of CS160 and a section of CS340 in 99F term

Tags: mysql, select

The schema is as follows:

```
Student(Snum, Sname)
Course(Cnum, Cname)
Professor(Pnum,Pname, Dept, Office)
Class(Cnum, Term, Section, Instructor)
```

How can I join the two selects below to get Instructors who taught both CS160 and CS340?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Instructor FROM class
WHERE Term = "99F" AND Cnum = "CS160"
SELECT DISTINCT Instructor FROM class
WHERE Term = "99F" AND Cnum = "CS340"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySql doesn't have `intersect`, you have to do a self-join; something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.Instructor FROM class a inner join class b
using (Instructor,Term)
where a.Term "99F" and a.Cnum = "CS160" and b.Cnum = "CS340"
```

---

Edit: *with* intersect, you just put the `intersect` specifier between the 2 queries you had in your example (and you can omit the "distinct"; "intersect" returns only distinct values):

```
SELECT Instructor FROM class
WHERE Term = "99F" AND Cnum = "CS160"
INTERSECT
SELECT Instructor FROM class
WHERE Term = "99F" AND Cnum = "CS340"
```

`intersect` is part of the SQL standard, but MySql doesn't implement it. SQL implementations that do have `intersect` include Oracle and Postgres.

See also [mySQL versus Standard SQL](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/my-nonstandard.html#intersect)

Comment: thanks! after playing around with it, here is the final answer: `SELECT DISTINCT a.Instructor FROM class a join class b
on a.Instructor = b.Instructor
where a.Term = "99F" and b.Term = "99F" and a.Cnum = "CS160" and b.Cnum = "CS340"`

Comment: out of curiousity, how would one do the same thing WITH intersect? what languages have intersect?

Comment: thanks! i understand it now, and am going to have to learn oracle someday so that is very helpful.